# GTK+3: Ask confirmation before application quit

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm trying to ask the user for confirmation when he tries to quit my application. But I don't know how to catch all the different ways the user can quit the app: there's the 'X' button on the window, Alt+F4, I myself use Alt+Shift+Q on i3.

How would one go o about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should connect to the `delete-event` of the `Gtk.Window` you use at the application window. The `delete-event` allows you to show a confirmation dialog, and, depending on the user response, you can either return `True` — meaning that you handled the event, and that the signal propagation should be stopped; or return `False` — meaning that the signal propagation should continue, which will cause the `destroy()` method to be called on the widget.

The `delete-event` signal is emitted in response of a termination request from the window manager; for instance, when using the window menu; a key combination like Alt+F4; or the window's "Close" button.

A simple example demonstrating the above:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gio
from gi.repository import Gtk

class AppWindow (Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.ApplicationWindow.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(200, 200)

    # Override the default handler for the delete-event signal
    def do_delete_event(self, event):
        # Show our message dialog
        d = Gtk.MessageDialog(transient_for=self,
                              modal=True,
                              buttons=Gtk.ButtonsType.OK_CANCEL)
        d.props.text = 'Are you sure you want to quit?'
        response = d.run()
        d.destroy()

        # We only terminate when the user presses the OK button
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            print('Terminating...')
            return False

        # Otherwise we keep the application open
        return True

def on_activate(app):
    # Show the application window
    win = AppWindow()
    win.props.application = app
    win.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create an application instance
    app = Gtk.Application(application_id='com.example.ExampleApp', flags=0)

    # Use ::activate to show our application window
    app.connect('activate', on_activate)
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! Will try to implement this.

Comment: How do you do this when your main class is of type `class App(Gtk.Application)`?

Comment: This does not really answer the question as it is about handling the closing event of a single window, which is not the entry point in case of a signal or call to `app.quit()`. It is not applicable to applications with multiple windows or no windows at all. Of course there is `do_shutdown()` but it's for cleanup tasks, too late to cancel the process.

Comment: The `quit()` method cannot be caught, as it will terminate the application immediately, regardless of open windows; it should also not be used unless you're literally forcing the application to terminate programmatically. The original question was for catching user interaction on an application's window.